# Find unique month-year combinations from cells

Tags: matlab, date, unique, cell-array

I have a cell array `Date` with dates (day-month-year) in it. 
I want to find, for every cell, what the unique months and year combinations are.

[image]

The date time format looks like this

```
'20-Oct-2013 00:00:00'
'20-Oct-2013 03:00:00'
'20-Oct-2013 06:00:00'
'20-Oct-2013 09:00:00'
'20-Oct-2013 12:00:00'
'20-Oct-2013 15:00:00'
'20-Oct-2013 18:00:00'
'20-Oct-2013 21:00:00'
'21-Oct-2013 00:00:00'
```

Simplified example

```
cell1:
1-1-2001
2-1-2001
2-5-1191
5-6-2000
9-8-2000

cell2:
7-8-2008
8-8-2008
16-8-2008
9-6-2009
```

I want my output to be

```
cell1:
1-2001
5-1191
6-2000
8-2000

cell2:
8-2008
6-2009
```

The code I am currently using is

```
for i = 1:lenNF %76 cells
   unique([month(Date{i});year(Date{i})])
end
```

This gives me the following output, which makes impossible to determine which month belongs to which year.

```
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   9
  10
  11
  12
2010
2011
```

What do I need to adjust in my code to make sure I still know which month belongs to which year?

Comment: In which format are your date ? A char array ? A string array ? A datetime array ? Please provide a working example that respect the matlab synthax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array per cell with just day-month in a two column structure. Then it's a simple call to [`unique(array,'rows')`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html?s_tid=doc_ta#d117e1553944), where the `'rows'` option makes sure to find unique rows, in your unique day-month combinations.

You can build your array by calling `array=datevec()` on each cell, then `unique(array(:,1:2))` will do, as the first column contains the year, the second the month.